# How can I figure out when I'll be able to write call options of a stock?

Tags: options, ipo, covered-call-writing

I have a 200 Zynga shares. I'm wondering when I'll be able to write call options?

I see Groupon has options on it, but Pandora does not, so it seems it must not be just time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the CBOE, the Chicago Board of Options Exchange

I've requested options on several IPOs in the past. You mainly have to convince them that there is a market for them (or they won't be inclined to provide liquidity).

The CBOE could talk to the company in question to help convince them, or the CBOE will just tell you when the options will begin trading.

Oh yeah, sometimes they'll ask you who you work for, just try to avoid that question, they don't like to talk to individual/retail investors.

Answer (score 2):

You can't know. It's not like every stock has options traded on it, so until you either see the options listed or a company announcement that option will trade on a certain date, there's no way to be sure.